# POST data is visible in Fiddler despite HTTPS?

Tags: c#, http, post, https, fiddler

When on looking at the `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` methods on C#,
I just learnt about the `HTTP POST` and `HTTP GET` and the `HTTPS`

`HTTPS` means whatever data we send `will be encrypted so that it is secure`

Even when on submitting to some `POST` data to a `HTTPS` site while making a `HttpWebRequest`, `Fiddler` seems no problems to read the `username` and `password`. How?

```
POST https://someurl  HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: some-host
Content-Length: 84
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

j_username=admin&j_password=pass*&Submit=Login
```

The URL above is `HTTPS` probably means that all `datas are encrypted`.

How come then `Fiddler` know about the username and password ?

Comment: Because you are the client and your fiddler is on same endpoint as you are. `Transmission` to and from the server will be encrypted

Comment: Isn't Fiddler a MITM proxy? .. you're talking to Fiddler.. Fiddler talks to the other side.. therefore, Fiddler knows about the data in the request.. it gave you the certificate to encrypt it with.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Thanks. So, in the `case of using a browser`, the `browser` gives the `certificate` to encrypt the `form details` that I send?

Comment: No.. the browser talks directly to the other end. That is why Fiddler is considered a "Man In The Middle" (MITM) proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler is your [proxy in certain sense](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/knowledgebase/proxy), he sits in-between you and the outside world.